# access to a UIViewController property from appDelegate class in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have created a UIViewController class in whiche I have set a UIbutton property and a public method to access it.
In my appDelegate class, I instantiate this view Controller, all is OK.
However, when I try to access call the method, Xamarin does not compile and return a NullReferenceException, although the UIButton is displayed on the screen.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT
Actually, I instantiated my components in viewdidload, but I have to do ti in the constructor.

Comment: place the code relating the instance creation and how you are calling the instance method...

Comment: user2223927: If you post your code, we can probably help you figure out what's wrong.